# Custom Editor does not mark scene dirty after changes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using a MonoBehavior with a serializable object to edit data in the editor. But when i add a custom editor the scene is not marked as dirty after changes anymore. So i can't save the changes. Undo.RecordObject seems not to work in this case, because it requires a object of type UnityEngine.Object

I've included a simple example below

```
using UnityEngine;
public class DataManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Data data;
}

using System;
[Serializable]
public class Data
{
    public int num;
}

using UnityEditor;
[CustomEditor(typeof(DataManager))]
public class DataEditor : Editor
{
    private DataManager dataManager;

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        dataManager = target as DataManager;
        dataManager.data.num = EditorGUILayout.IntField(dataManager.data.num);
    }
}
```

Edit: One solution i found is this. But this will get quite annoying with many variables. There should be a better way for this

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

[CustomEditor(typeof(DataManager))]
public class DataEditor : Editor
{
    private DataManager dataManager;

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        dataManager = target as DataManager;

        int num = EditorGUILayout.IntField(dataManager.data.num);
        if (num != dataManager.data.num)
        {
            dataManager.data.num = num;
            EditorSceneManager.MarkSceneDirty(SceneManager.GetActiveScene());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is not marked as dirty? Your code looks fine, even though it doesn't work to have more than one class in a MonoBehaviour object, but I suppose thats only as an example.

Comment: Yes, i'm sure. When i remove the custom editor it and when i add it again it does not

Comment: Are you sure that you are not just cancelling the input on the IntField, so the value is not changed?

Comment: It's definitely changed. It stays the same when i switch between gameobjects, but when i load a different scene in editor and got back it change is gone

Comment: I don't recommend it, but try using `EditorUtility.SetDirty(target)`. Try using your script object as the target and see if it works.

Comment: Hmm this also seems to does nothing. Maybe i also should mention i'm using Unity 5.4.0f2

Comment: Hmm thats weird ... where did you add the `EditorUtility.SetDirty(target)` part?

Comment: After the EditorGUILayout part in OnInspectorGUI

Comment: I found a solution that works and updated my first post. But i'm not sure this is really the best way

Comment: I've the same problem and found an awesome answer here: [https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/125698/how-to-edit-and-persist-serializable-assets-in-the-editor-window](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/125698/how-to-edit-and-persist-serializable-assets-in-the-editor-window)